# How to get a timeline with zero observations for stores not selling

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue with a table I would like to create. 
I have a table for accumulated sales for each store for each day where the store had a sale. Meaning that if the store didn't have a sale on a specific day, there's no line for this observation.

what I would like is a line for each store for each day, also the days where the store didn't have any sales, in this case the daily sales would just be zero.

I've tried making a full outer join between a daily generate_series and the table mentioned above.

```
select
  timeline::date as date,
  store_rev.store_name,
  store_rev.store_daily_rev
FROM generate_series(
    '2017-03-01',
    now(),
    '1 day') AS timeline
FULL OUTER JOIN(select
               r.date,
               r.store_name,
               r.store_daily_rev,
               FROM revenue r) store_rev ON timeline.date=store_rev.date
```

But this doesn't give me a row of zero if the store didn't have any sales. 
Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that column `date` in table `revenue` is type `DATE`

I modifited your query, try this:

```
select
    timeline::date as date,
    store_rev.store_name,
    store_rev.store_daily_rev
from
(
    select
    timeline::date as date
    from
    generate_series('2017-03-01', now(),'1 day') AS timeline
) timeline
JOIN(select
     r.date,
     r.store_name,
     r.store_daily_rev,
     FROM revenue r) store_rev ON timeline.date::date = store_rev.date::date;
```

Comment: You need a `left join` not an inner join

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `cross join` followed by a `left join`.  This will get all combinations:

```
select timeline.date, s.store_name,
       coalesce(r.store_daily_rev, 0) as store_daily_rev
from generate_series('2017-03-01', now(), '1 day') as timeline(date) cross join
     (select distinct r.store_name from revenue r) s left join
     revenue r
     on r.store_name = s.store_name and r.date = timeline.date;
```

The `cross join` generates all the rows (the combinations of dates and stores).  The `left join` brings in the revenue values for the store/dates that have them.

Comment: That works. Awesome! Never head about a cross join before, but that was just what I needed. so cool much appreciated!